# modify rows of a table as per null values

Tags: kdb

I am a novice at kdb+q. I've come across the following problem involving tables in one of my exercises.

Given a keyed table t with single key = id, write a function which returns another table T such that:

a) For each row in t, there are as many rows in T as non-null values in that row of t.

b) Each row in T contains exactly one non-null value which should be the same as the corresponding non-null value in t.

Examples:

```
If t is

id |a    b
----------
1  |1    1
2  |1    0n

then T would be

id | a    b
-----------
1  |1    0n
1  |0n   1
2  |1    0n

and if t is
id  | a    b    c
------------------ 
1   | 1    3    0n
2   | 2    0n   4
3   | 0n   0n   5

then T would be

id |a     b    c
----------------
1  |1     0n   0n
1  |0n    3    0n
2  |2     0n   0n
2  |0n    0n   4
3  |0n    0n   5
```

From what I inferred from the question, if we treat each row as an n-tuple, it's projecting the vector along each of it's n dimensions where 0n is behaving like 0 in usual Cartesian vector.

I tried writing some functions but accessing each row and taking care of nulls has been a trouble.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: SUggest you take "sql" off the tag list - this is nothing to do with sql :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've came out:

```
q)f
{ungroup x{(x*y)@\:where not null get x}\:{(x;x)#1,x#0N}count[cols x]-1}
q)t:([id:1 2 3]a:1 2 0N;b:3 0N 0N;c:0N 4 5)
q)t
id| a b c
--| -----
1 | 1 3
2 | 2   4
3 |     5
q)f t
id a b c
--------
1  1
1    3
2  2
2      4
3      5
```

Comment: Really enjoyed reading this answer! brilliant! My only point would be that you risk losing type information with type promotion taking place in the multiplication. I tried doing some typecasting at the end, but it slowed down too much. Not a big deal, but just thought was worth highlighting

Comment: Good to hear, I do agree that type promotion will take place if the nulls are in different type. Surely there is some way to get around it :)

Comment: I tried making the nulls you take at the start fit the types of the cols, but you still lose certain info in the multiplication (for example, short*short -> int  q)(type each n)~type each (1;2h;3)*n:(1;0Nh;0n)
Any trick aside from type casts? I would certainly like to learn if so, thanks!

Comment: Tried asking around here but don't think there's a clean way to get around the type promotion. There should be a good reason for short short to int promotion (avoid overflow maybe?). But for now, type casting is the way to go :)

Comment: Yeah, the short*short->int definitely seems to be to avoid overflow. Thanks for asking around! Glad to see the `kdb` tag getting a lot of activity recently. very useful for me to start picking up tricks of the trade.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, but significantly slower than @WooiKent Lee's answer. I screw up with the sorting and removing completely null rows (but mainly with the former).

```
q)breakout:{k xasc n where any each not null v#n:(0#x0) upsert/((k:keys x),/:v:cols value x)#\:x0:0!x}
q)breakout t
id a b c
--------
1  1
1    3
2  2
2      4
3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will take care of the types (i'll spend some time and optimize it)

```
q)t:([ id: 1 2] a: 1 1;b:1 0n;c: 0N 0Ni)  //checkout the meta
id| a b c
--| -----
1 | 1 1
2 | 1

q)f:{[t] ungroup {st:count[x]#0#enlist x;d:(enlist each key[x])!'(enlist each value[x]); key[x]!flip r where not all each null each r:value each upsert'[st;d]} each   t }

q)f[t]
id a b c
--------
1  1
1    1
2  1

q)meta f[t]
c | t f a
--| -----
id| j
a | j
b | f
c | i
```